# Where can I find the reverse light fuse on a 2004 Toyota Vios

Tags: toyota, vios, fuse-panel

I am not familiar with the fuse box and the diagram is blurred already. There is a 4x4 set of fuses in the fuse box. I want to know which is for the reverse light.

Comment: [Here is the diagram](http://i372.photobucket.com/albums/oo163/ctscott329/Yaris%20-%201st%20Gen/2002FusePanel.jpg~original), (I believe) though I don't see a fuse listed for the reverse lights on it. It could be controlled under the tail lights, but not sure.

Comment: Did you check the fuse details in owners manual?